# Javascript set timeout not working in web worker

Tags: javascript, settimeout, web-worker

I have some JavaScript code in a web worker as shown below.

```
onmessage = function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
        postMessage(event.data + " ,then sent back to the main thread");
    }, 4000);
};
```

Whenever I run the code the set timeout portion just skips basically without executing. My main JavaScript code calls the worker every 2 seconds with set interval that works correctly in my main section of code. However this section of code is not working. Does anybody know why? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to override existing [onmessage event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197057(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the output of this?

```
onmessage = function(event){
    console.log("onmessage event is:",event);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("timeout from onmessage, event is:",event);
        postMessage(event.data + " ,then sent back to the main thread");
    }, 4000);
};
```

I can't see a problem with the code unless event is null but that  would cause an Error you could see that in the console as well.

Comment: console is not exposed in the running context of web workers.

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be that post message is executing in the context of setTimeout is usually Window which is not defined in a worker, try adding self in front of post message to make sure it's in the right scope.

```
self.onmessage = function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.postMessage(event.data + " ,then sent back to the main thread");
    }, 4000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general structure for a web worker that does work.

```
// I've found this syntax for handling the initial message event
// to be the most reliable
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

  // Do what you need to do here, i.e:
  // for (var p in self) { result += '\n' + p + '=' + self[p]; }
  // and then post 'result' as the return message on log it from
  // the main thread to discover what objects are exposed by the
  // VM inside the worker.

  // Then 'return' the result
  self.postMessage('this is my response');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry to resurrect a very old question — but as this is the top search engine result I wanted to provide another answer.*

As a result of JavaScript's single-threaded approach,
`setTimeout` only fires when the current *call stack* is clear. When `setTimeout` is within an infinite-loop (or a very long running operation), it will not fire until that loop/operation concludes.

For example, you might read the below code and expect `"Surprise!"` after 1 second. However, the string will only be logged once the loop concludes (after roughly five seconds.)

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Surprise!");
}, 1000); // 1 second

const start = new Date().getTime();

while ((new Date().getTime()) - start < 5000) {
    // do nothing
}
```